# evaluate method takes long time - PMML models using Jpmml

Tags: java, performance, apache-spark-mllib, pmml

Today I am using Jpmml in order to load pmml models in my code. but the'evaluate' method takes long time. 
Here is the working code today :

```
    String modelPath = "....";
    ModelEvaluatorFactory factory = ModelEvaluatorFactory.newInstance();
    InputStream in = new   ByteArrayInputStream(modelPath.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    PMML pmmlModel = JAXBUtil.unmarshalPMML(new StreamSource(in)); 
    ModelEvaluator<?> evaluator = factory.newModelManager(pmmlModel);
    List<FieldName> activeFields = evaluator.getActiveFields();

    Map<FieldName, FieldValue> defaultFeatures = new HashMap<>();

    //after filling the 'defaultFeatures' the line below takes long time
    Map<FieldName, ?> results = evaluator.evaluate(defaultFeatures);
```

PMML example :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <PMML xmlns="http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_2" version="4.2">
    <Header>
        <Application name="JPMML-SkLearn" version="1.0-SNAPSHOT"/>
        <Timestamp>2017-01-22T14:18:05Z</Timestamp>
    </Header>
    <DataDictionary>
        <DataField name="GENDER" optype="categorical" dataType="string">
            <Value value="0"/>
            <Value value="1"/>
        </DataField>
        <DataField name="1GA_" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
    //67000 rows of datafield
    </DataDictionary>
    <TransformationDictionary>
        <DefineFunction name="logit" optype="continuous" dataType="double">
            <ParameterField name="value" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
            <Apply function="/">
                <Constant dataType="double">1</Constant>
                <Apply function="+">
                    <Constant dataType="double">1</Constant>
                    <Apply function="exp">
                        <Apply function="*">
                            <Constant dataType="double">-1</Constant>
                            <FieldRef field="value"/>
                        </Apply>
                    </Apply>
                </Apply>
            </Apply>
        </DefineFunction>
    </TransformationDictionary>
     <MiningModel functionName="classification">
        <MiningSchema>
            <MiningField name="GENDER" usageType="target"/>
            <MiningField name="1GA_"/>
      //67000 rows of MiningField
       </MiningSchema>
        <Output>
            <OutputField name="probability_0" feature="probability" value="0"/>
            <OutputField name="probability_1" feature="probability" value="1"/>
        </Output>
        <LocalTransformations>
            <DerivedField name="x1" optype="continuous" dataType="double">
                <FieldRef field="1GA_"/>
            </DerivedField>
       //100000 rows
        </LocalTransformations>
         <Segmentation multipleModelMethod="modelChain">
            <Segment id="1">
                <True/>
                <RegressionModel functionName="regression">
                    <MiningSchema>
                        <MiningField name="1GA_"/>
                  </MiningSchema>
                    <Output>
                        <OutputField name="decisionFunction_1"    feature="predictedValue"/>
                        <OutputField name="logitDecisionFunction_1" optype="continuous" dataType="double" feature="transformedValue">
                            <Apply function="logit">
<FieldRef field="decisionFunction_1"/>
                            </Apply>
                        </OutputField>
                    </Output>
                    <RegressionTable intercept="-5.303370169392045">
           <NumericPredictor name="x1" coefficient="0.18476274186559316"/>
          //100000 rows of NumericPredictor

      </RegressionTable>
                 </RegressionModel>
              </Segment>
              <Segment id="2">
                  <True/>
                <RegressionModel functionName="regression">
                    <MiningSchema>
                        <MiningField name="logitDecisionFunction_1"/>
                    </MiningSchema>
                    <Output>
                        <OutputField name="logitDecisionFunction_0"  
     feature="predictedValue"/>
                    </Output>
                    <RegressionTable intercept="1.0">
            <NumericPredictor name="logitDecisionFunction_1" 

           coefficient="-1.0"/>
                        </RegressionTable>
                    </RegressionModel>
                </Segment>
                <Segment id="3">
                    <True/>
                    <RegressionModel functionName="classification">
                        <MiningSchema>
                            <MiningField name="GENDER" usageType="target"/>
                            <MiningField name="logitDecisionFunction_1"/>
                            <MiningField name="logitDecisionFunction_0"/>
                        </MiningSchema>
                        <RegressionTable intercept="0.0" targetCategory="1">
                            <NumericPredictor name="logitDecisionFunction_1" 


     coefficient="1.0"/>
                    </RegressionTable>
                <RegressionTable intercept="0.0" targetCategory="0">
                        <NumericPredictor name="logitDecisionFunction_0"   


       coefficient="1.0"/>
                        </RegressionTable>
                    </RegressionModel>
                </Segment>
         </Segmentation>
        </MiningModel>
        </PMML>
```

There is a thought of trying to use MLlib instead of Jpmml.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "load"? Is it "parse PMML document into an in-memory data structure" or "execute PMML document"?

Your code appears to be aim for the latter. But it will definitely fail, because the `JAXBUtil#unmarshalPMML(Source)` method is invoked with a byte array, which doesn't contain a valid PMML document (no XML parser will accept `"....".getBytes("UTF-8")`).

Also, what do you mean by "takes long time"? The JAXB framework has one-time initialization cost of around ~1 second. After that it can unmarshal ~200 to 500 MB (that's megabytes) of PMML content per second. How much more do you need?

Comment: Hi, the code is working. What takes long time is the evaluate method. therefore I thought using MLlib folder.

Comment: So, by "load" you actually meant "execute". JPMML is executing the model according to the execution plan that is stored in your PMML document. The execution is slow because your PMML document contains an ineffective execution plan. What kind of software did you use to generate this PMML document? Was is Apache Spark's own `PMMLExportable` interface, which is known to generate notoriously ineffective execution plans (eg. can expand a single categorical data column to many thousands continuous data columns).

Comment: I  added the pmml schema. Thanks for your help

Comment: That's the source of your performance problems: `//67000 rows of datafield`. Basically, JPMML is expected to execute a function that takes 67'000 ("sixty seven THOUSAND") arguments, and you're unhappy about its performance? You need to refactor the execution plan that is stored in your PMML document. In this context, you need to figure out what those 67'000 DataField elements really represent. For example, perhaps they represent 67 categorical features, each of which is 1000 category levels "deep"? After the refactoring, this 67-argument function would evaluate 1000 times faster.

Comment: And your code examples demonstrate that you're using outdated JPMML libraries both on the conversion and evaluation side. You should definitely upgrade to JPMML-SkLearn 1.2(.6) and JPMML-Evaluator 1.3(.4). The performance improvement should be noticeable, but quite naturally it won't be enough to make 67'000-argument functions fly.

Comment: Your suggestion regarding changing the execution plan reduced the average execution time from ~30ms to ~1.3 ms. Thank you!

Comment: @userit1985 How many DataField elements in your refactored execution plan? Over/under 1'000?